# Assigning object to method call

Tags: c++

I have a class whose name is YourClass. And my problem is WHY compiler do NOT generate an error for following code?

```
YourClass AMethod(){ return YourClass();}
AMethod() = YourClass();
```

[In this case IN MY OPINION AMethod just return a value (I mean it do not have a l-value).]

EDIT:
If I can do that above why I can not do following

```
int AMethod(){ return a;}
AMethod() = 5;
```

Comment: Which compiler/platform are you using?

Comment: @Bill VS2008 "required - at least 15 characters:)"

Comment: @Mark-I don't have a problem with code. I have a method that returns a class instance and I can make an assignment to that method call. I have Java prog. background so i think there should be a compiler error but there wasn't.

Comment: I did that in VS2008 and now I tried it in CodeGear. CodeGear thinks like me[Thanks to Embercadero] and produced an error "l-value required". I should ask a new question "what is the problem in VS2008 compiler [or CodeGear]?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT1:** I think I miss understood the question first time.

The standard says:
3.10 Lvalues and rvalues

> The result of calling a function that
>   does not return a reference is an
>   rvalue. User defined operators are
>   functions, and whether such operators
>   expect or yield lvalues is determined
>   by their parameter and return types.

The standard says nothing in this paragraph, except that user-defined types and primitive types are the same. If the return of a function is not a reference, then it is not an l-value. There is however an interesting commentary on the same page:

> 47) Expressions such as invocations of
>   constructors and of functions that
>   return a class type refer to objects,
>   and the implementation can invoke a
>   member function upon such objects, but
>   the expressions are not lvalues.

So basically in your example:

```
AMethod() = YourClass();
```

AMethod returns a user-defined type on which the function:

```
AMethod().operator=(YourClass());
```

is executed. Still, it is not an l-value. In fact, you could have empty statements in C++, or statement that consist of an r-value only!:

```
5;;; // correct C++ code!
```

---

**EDIT2:**

Consider this example:

```
if( &(YourClass() + YourClass()) == &YourClass() )
{
....
}
```

The expression `&(YourClass() + YourClass())` must yield an l-value so the whole expression becomes correct. It compiles fine on VC but it gives this little warning:

```
warning C4238: nonstandard extension used : class rvalue used as lvalue
```

Obviously the above line was wrong by C++ standards but VC just allows it!

---

Because you asked it so. First, a fresh instance of `YourClass` is returned by `AMethod`. Then, it is assigned another fresh instance. Of course in C++ you can say what ever you want. So, to prevent the assignment statement, just return `const YourClass`. In this case, the object becomes "**readable**" only:

```
const YourClass AMethod(){ return YourClass();}
```

This is the same in case you are overloading binary operators. For example, if you overload `operator+` for a class, then you can do with `const` or without it.

```
// '+' operator is defined as a friend operator not a member.
friend YourClass operator+(const YourClass& lhs, const YourClass& rhs)
{
...
}
```

If you did it that way, you could have meaningless statement like the following:

```
(a + b) = c;
```

Where the expression `(a + b)` is not useful because it represents only a value, not a variable we control, it produces a temp variable.

Comment: Aw, you beat me by 6 seconds :|

Comment: Seems like a good answer, but when I tried the example code I got errors. And I'm quite surprised that the compiler wouldn't at least generate a warning at using a temporary for an lvalue.

Comment: @Mark Thanks. Do you mean the second example? I assumed that the operator is defined as a friend operator not a member. I'll edit the post to clarify that :)

Comment: I meant the example posted in the original question gave an error. Sorry I didn't make that clear. It makes me wonder how relevant the question is though, and whether your answer makes sense.

Comment: @Mark: This `struct YourClass { YourClass& operator=(const YourClass &) {return *this;} AMethod(){ return YourClass();} int main() { AMethod() = YourClass(); }` compiles just fine for me.

Comment: A good answer, though it's also worth explicitly spelling out the assignment as what it really is - i.e. `AMethod().operator=(YourClass())`. IMO, this makes it very clear what's actually going on right away.

Answer (score 2):

`AMethod` returns an *rvalue*. In C++ you can call member functions, even modifying member functions, on an rvalue of *user-defined type*. And sometimes this is just what you want.

```
os.get_disk_accessor(0).wipe(); // wipe() might not be a const member function
```

However, you can not invoke operations on rvalues of *built-in* types:

```
int f();
f() = 5; // won't compile
++f();   // won't either
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
AMethod()
```

creates and returns a class object, and the expression

```
AMethod() = YourClass();
```

creates and assigns a second class object to the first object.

Comment: However, the interesting this is that, if your replace `YourClass` with a built-in, this doesn't work. See my reply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506727/1506893#1506893

Answer (score 0):

I think that 1'st version compiled because YourClass have a default constructor, destructor, copy constructor and ***assignment operator*** which called AMethod() = YourClass();.
int AMethod(){ return a;}
AMethod() = 5;
This code doesn't compile because there is not a rvalue.